# How to choose Redis databaseId in Azure for CacheManager?

Tags: azure, redis, cachemanager

I have a .NET application in Azure that uses Redis as cache through [CacheManager](http://cachemanager.michaco.net/). Application uses deployment slots. I want to have different Redis database IDs for different slots. Test/Staging/Prod slots use Redis databaseId 0/1/2.

Is it anyhow possible to set the databaseId programmatically in CacheManager while keeping the rest of the configuration (IP, port, ssl, key etc) in web.config file?
Only the database number vary and it is stored in Azure appSetting for every slot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do exactly what I asked about with CacheManager. At least at the moment. Once the configuration of CacheManager is build from web.config it is readonly.

But there is a workaround for different Redis databases for different deployment slots:

1. Add Redis connection string in *connectionStrings* section of *web.config*
   Include database ID in the connection string.
2. Refer to this connection string in *cacheManager*->*managers* section.
   Look at the example here
   https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager/blob/dev/test/CacheManager.Tests/app.config
3. Use *web.config* transformation or attach different connection strings to different deployment slots in Azure.